# Android - detect switching network manually

Tags: android, android-wifi

Is there any way I can detect if user switched to a different network manually(= not by connecting automatically to a network in PNL)?

I know that for automatic + manual connection I can use `BroadcastReceiver` on `android.net.wifi.STATE_CHANGE`, but It doesn't say if it happand manually or auto

Comment: You just need to query any change in netif...use the latest usable netif to get its ip address for reconnection

Comment: You can refer to github kouchat android how it is done ConnectionWorker

Comment: I'm not sure that you understood my question, or maybe I missed something..?    I'm not looking for the changes in the network interface (ConnectionWorker  uses the android API - NetworkInterface). I need to know ,no matter in which interface,when a connection happens if it was as a result of the user clicking on the device wifi screen or the device behavior.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/connectivity-monitoring.html

Comment: I know I can detect changes in wifi state this way but I can't tell who caused it (the user or the device).